# nodejs/javascript variable retaining its old value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am using the nodejs request module from here: https://github.com/mikeal/request -- There are cookies involved but not part of this code.

Excuse the non-optimized code, I've been trying various stuff trying to fix this problem with no success. I have this simple script:

```
function getPage(curpage)
{
    if(curpage <= pages)
    {
        var newpage = curpage + 1;
        console.log('getting page '+newpage );

        request.get({ uri: 'http://someurl.com/test', qs: { p : newpage }}, function(error, response, body) {
            if(error)
            {
                [...]
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(response.req.path);
            }
            getPage(newpage);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("We're done!\n");
        process.exit();
    }
}
```

The problem here, is my response.req.path seems to get stuck at 2. I get:

```
getting page 1
/id/bradpitt5/inventoryhistory?p=1
getting page 2
/id/bradpitt5/inventoryhistory?p=2
getting page 3
/id/bradpitt5/inventoryhistory?p=2
getting page 4
/id/bradpitt5/inventoryhistory?p=2
```

As you can see, the "newpage" is used properly when getting the page, but the request path is set wrong? I can't make sense out of this. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong here?

I just start with getPage(0);

I also did this using a different method, just to make sure I wasn't crazy:

```
for( var i = 1; i <= pages; i++ ) {
    urls.push( {'url' : 'http://somepage.com/test?p='+ i, 'done' : false } );
}

function getNextPage() {
    for(var i = 0; i < pages; i++ ) {
        if( urls[i].done == false ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if( urls[i] && urls[i].done == false ) {
        urls[i].done = true;
        console.log( 'requesting: '+ urls[ i ].url );

        request.get( urls[ i ].url, function(error, response, body) {
                if(error) {
                    [...]
                } else {
                    console.log( 'received: '+ response.req.path +' ok. ');
                }
                getNextPage();
            }
        );
    } else {
        console.log("we're done!");
        process.exit();
    }
}
```

This also gets stuck at page 2.

Comment: If you change the flow from recursion to iteration, do you still get the same result?

Comment: I changed this completely with a while loop going through an array for testing and I get the same thing. I'll post the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The implication is that:

```
{ uri: 'http://someurl.com/test', qs: { p : newpage }}
```

is not being updated each time `request.get()` is called. I wonder if it is worth trying to create a new variable:

```
var options = {
    uri: 'http://someurl.com/test',
    qs: {
        p: newpage
    }
};

// let's debug just to be sure
console.log( "  options = %s", JSON.stringify( options, null, 2 ) );

request.get( options, function(error, response, body) {
    ...
```

I don't know if this is the case but I wonder if the object created within the function call isn't evaluated just once.

Comment: I posted a 2nd example above using completely different logic with the same result, it's really odd.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I only had "2 pages" of data, and the site I was requesting from redirected to the last page if I was trying to go higher than the number of pages. :(